# Deferring the coroutine yield

Tags: c++, ssl, lambda, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

My problem seems to stem from the fact that openssl has no continuation passing style for callbacks like server-name-indication (SNI) but I'm trying to force one into it.

I want to avoid blocking a worker thread on reading the clients SSL hello, and avoid blocking a worker thread while I refuse to return the SNI callback while waiting for a server ssl handshake to complete (so I can re-sign the server certificate).

For an `asio` bsaed re-signing SSL proxy using the `boost::asio::ssl::stream` wrapper for openssl.

I use `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_*` helpers to get a callback during SSL negotiation with the client.

Currently make sure that I use a coroutine and handshake inside a lambda from a `boost::asio::spawn` on a `strand`. I use a server-name-indication callback (suitably wrapped) so that I can block the client handshake during the server handshake but without blocking a worker thread (the co-routine will bw suspended.

```
boost::asio::spawn(strand_, [=](boost::asio::yield_context yield){
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  boost::system::error_code ec_server;

  sni_callback = [=,&ec](std::string server_name) {
    server_->ssl_connection->ssl_socket.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, yield[ec_server]);
    /* Todo: sign the server certificate and replace the ssl_socket SSL_CTX here */
  };

  ssl_connection->ssl_socket.handshake(boost::asio::ssl:stream_base::server, ec);

  if (! ec) ec = ec_server;

  handler(ec);
});
```

But I realise that the ssl handshake with the client will block a worker thread util it completes.

I tried an asyc handshake with the client:

```
  ssl_connection->ssl_socket.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl:stream_base::server, yield[ec]);
```

but the program segfaults in the yield during the SNI handler wrapper.

No doubt this is because the non-blocking handshake does not invoke the SNI handler on the co-routine - and the only way it can do that (without blocking a worker thread) is if all it's internal handlers are invoked on the coroutine, but I know it uses an internal strand for it's own work.

With all shared library symbols loaded (even for libstdc++, etc) the stacktrace is:

```
.#0  0x000000000000000c in ?? ()
.#1  0x00007f8200000000 in ?? ()
.#2  0x00007f829e15043d in CRYPTO_free (str=0x7f828c054640) at mem.c:401
.#3  0x00007f829e1faba5 in ASN1_primitive_free (pval=<optimized out>, it=<optimized out>) at tasn_fre.c:261
.#4  0x00007f828c052250 in ?? ()
.#5  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
.#6  0x00007f828c0524f0 in ?? ()
.#7  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
.#8  0x00007f829d30c560 in ?? ()
.#9  0x00007f829d30c710 in ?? ()
.#10 0x000000000000000c in ?? ()
.#11 0x00007f828c0180b4 in ?? ()
.#12 0x00007f829e15043d in CRYPTO_free (str=0x7f828c052250) at mem.c:401
.#13 0x00007f829e1eb2cf in EVP_PKEY_CTX_free (ctx=<optimized out>) at pmeth_lib.c:381
.#14 0x00007f829e1de1e2 in EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup (ctx=0x7f829d30c590) at digest.c:394
.#15 0x00007f829e5041c1 in tls1_PRF (digest_mask=262400, seed1=0x7f829e5213fb, seed1_len=15, seed2=0x7f829d30c720, seed2_len=-1639094656, seed3=0x0, 
seed3_len=-1657747584, seed4=0x23635fe, seed4_len=-1657747600, sec=0x7f82a0035df0 "\321\365M\236\202\177", slen=<optimized out>, out1=0x7f82a0035178 "d\356@", 
out2=0x7f82a0038508 "", olen=4247053, seed5_len=0, seed5=0x0) at t1_enc.c:272
.#16 0x00007f829e4dbb18 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
.#17 0x00007f829d30c780 in ?? ()
.#18 0x00000000023635fe in ?? ()
.#19 0x00007f829d30c770 in ?? ()
.#20 0x00007f82a0035df0 in ?? ()
.#21 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I expect that this is a stack-trace during cleanup from a fault.

To invoke the SNI handler on the same coroutine I think that I need to make all of the ssl::stream intermediate callbacks occur on that coroutine. 
Is there a direct way to do that?

I wonder if boost::ssl could invoke it's handlers in it's own strand but still on the coroutine stack, that's the only fix, but I don't know if the asio_handler_invoke business with the handler has enough magic to cause that to happen even if it were possible. How can you nest asio_handler_invoke to run on a coroutine (strand-y in itself) AND via an internal strand.

Also should I be using asio_invoke_handler in the last line of my example?

Comment: The exact error/stack trace you're getting would be helpful.

Comment: One would think so, but the stack trace is very sparse even with all shared library symbols loaded, I'll edit the question to show.

Comment: Are you trying to intercept SSL connections and spoof the upstream certificate? SSL capable proxy? I'm getting lost in your question because there's actually many questions in there. I'm trying to find a single point to focus on. Looking at the trace, looks like a key you're signing with is falling out of scope or somehow being destroyed in the async handshake. Plus you don't want to really do the spoofing in the handshake phase, you should do a `::peek` read on the incoming SSL connection to snoop the host before even starting to talk to the incoming SSL socket.

Comment: You need to already have your spoofed certificate set on the server context before you invoke the handshake process.

Comment: I am intercepting SSL connections to spoof the upstream certificate dynamically. That much works. Things ought not to be able to go out of scope with an .async_handshake(..., yield[ec]) and more than they can go out of scope with a blocking .handshake(...), but I'll add some debugging to check for that as it is a good thought. It's not always possible to ::peek if you also want to intercept starttls part way through a connection.  It is possible (and recommended) to replace the ssl context during the SNI callback, that's the purpose of it, but new hosts need a certificate creating dynamically.

Comment: I've written an intercepting HTTPS proxy and I've always just done a peek when I get an inbound connection on 443, I'm guess you're intercepting all encrypted comms like mail. Can you post the error code you're getting on the crash with the async handshake?

Comment: Yeah... And it works, but I hoped to use coroutine. I'll ask on the bossy mailing list

Comment: Well don't give up hope here, I've upvoted, hopefully someone with the knowledge will come along. There are some very smart people that follow the boost-asio tag. :)

Comment: Thanks for your good questioning